# apache wsgi with flask opens only default apache page

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to run a flask app on apache wsgi, here is my virtualhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName 127.0.0.1
            ServerAdmin admin@128.199.248.116
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/classifier/classifier.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/classifier/classifier/>
                    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /templates/ /var/www/classifier/classifier/templates/
            <Directory /var/www/classifier/classifier/templates/>
                    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog /var/www/classifier/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog /var/www/classifier/access.log combined</VirtualHost>
```

and here is my wsgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/classifier/")

from classifier.server import app as application
application.secret_key = ''
```

when I try to access the server through the external ip address, I am getting Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. What am I doing wrong here?

~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `127.0.0.1` as `ServerName` for the `VirtualHost`. It should be the actual host name for the site which it will be accessed using.

If you only want to be able to access it via an IP address, or `localhost`, you need to add your configuration to the default (first) `VirtualHost` configuration, not create a separate one.

BTW, it is strongly recommended you use daemon mode of mod_wsgi rather than embedded mode as you are.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, if you want to access the server via the external IP address, you have to disable the default site configuration first.

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
service apache2 restart
```